# 'syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING' Adding google event tracking to button in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, google-analytics, wordpress

I'm attempting to add a google event tracking to a wordpress plugin. The code for the submit button in this plugin is:

```
{
        return "<input  type=\"submit\" ".
                "name=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_name()."\" ".
                "id=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_id()."\" ".
                "class=\"submit\" ".
                "value=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_text()."\" ".
                "onclick=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_script()."\" ".
                "  />\n";
    }
```

I'm trying to add google analytics tracking code `onclick=_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', 'Apply'])` to the above block, and eventually replace `'Apply'` with `fm_form_the_title()` which returns the title of the form.

The problem: No matter what arrangement of quotes I use when inserting the tracking code block, I am faced with an error 'syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING' or 'T_STRING' which shuts down the entire site.

EDIT: The code block above works, and does not need simplifying, and is part of a much larger project. My question is how to add `onclick=_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', 'Apply'])` and eventually replace `'Apply'` with `fm_form_the_title()` and NOT break my website.

Answer (score 3):

The following is valid though the code that is using this once it's returned could be throwing an error on either the parens, brackets, or single quotes. If this doesn't work take a look at where this is being used once it's returned and escape the special characters accordingly.

```
function yourfunc() {

  return "<input  type=\"submit\" ".
    "name=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_name()."\" ".
    "id=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_id()."\" ".
    "class=\"submit\" ".
    "value=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_text()."\" ".
    "onclick=\"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form',".
    "'Submit', '".fm_form_the_title()."']);".
    fm_form_submit_btn_script()."\"/>\n";

}
```

Try it without using single quotes in the array being passed to the _gaq.push method.

```
function yourfunc() {

  return "<input  type=\"submit\" ".
    "name=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_name()."\" ".
    "id=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_id()."\" ".
    "class=\"submit\" ".
    "value=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_text()."\" ".
    "onclick=\"_gaq.push([\"_trackEvent\", \"Form\",".
    "\"Submit\", \"".fm_form_the_title()."\"]);".
    fm_form_submit_btn_script()."\"/>\n";

}
```

I have to agree with the guys below though that the following is the best for both readability and future support.

```
function yourfunc() {

  return '<input  type="submit" '.
    'name="'.fm_form_submit_btn_name().'" '.
    'id="'.fm_form_submit_btn_id().'" '.
    'class="submit" '.
    'value="'.fm_form_submit_btn_text().'" '.
    'onclick="_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Form",'.
    '"Submit", "'.fm_form_the_title().'"]); '.
    fm_form_submit_btn_script().'"/>\n';

}
```

Comment: This changes the error from `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` to `syntax error, unexpected T_STRING` it also leaves out `"onclick=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_script()."\" ".`

Comment: Nevermind. I had a quote in the wrong place. It's back to `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` and still misses the `"onclick=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_script()."\" ".`

Comment: I updated my answer before I had my coffee this morning. Try what I posted above and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

How about simplyfing this with

```
return '<input  type="submit" '.
'name=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_name()."\" ".
'id="'.fm_form_submit_btn_id().'"'.
'class="submit"'.
'value=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_text().'"'.
'onclick="'.fm_form_submit_btn_script().'"'.
'  />\n';
```

Comment: Because that may break other things and doesn't do what I'm trying to accomplish. I just want to add google analytics event tracking code to the link above. The code works as displayed above. Adding event tracking code breaks it. I want to add `onclick=_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', 'Apply'])` without breaking my site.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're escaping the quotes to put in the function calls, why not use single quotes?

```
 return '<input  type="submit" '.
            'name="'.fm_form_submit_btn_name().'" '.
            'id="'.fm_form_submit_btn_id().'" '.
            'class="submit" '.
            'value="'.fm_form_submit_btn_text().'" '.
            'onclick="'.fm_form_submit_btn_script().'" '.
            '  />
         ';
```

Comment: EDIT: The code block above works, and does not need simplifying, and is part of a much larger project. My question is how to add onclick=_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Form', 'Submit', 'Apply']) and eventually replace 'Apply' with fm_form_the_title() and NOT break my website.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return '<input  type="submit" '.
'name=\"".fm_form_submit_btn_name(). '" '.
'id="'.fm_form_submit_btn_id().'" '.
'class="submit" ".
'value="'.fm_form_submit_btn_text().'" '.
'onclick="'.fm_form_submit_btn_script(). '" '.
' />';
```